# Why data-binding in Popups don't work, although DataContexts are identical?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

As I understand, `DataContext` is cascaded via the logical tree (or the visual tree, if logical tree is cut off). And if `DataContext` exists, then data-binding to one of its properties is possible.

And whenever I check it, I see that the `Popup`'s `DataContext` is the same `DataContext` object of the root `Window` object.

Given the above, why data-binding doesn't work with `Popup`s???

Here's the code I used for testing:

```
<Window x:Class="TestPopup.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:l="clr-namespace:TestPopup"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <l:ViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Margin="10" FontSize="30" Click="Button_OnClick">
            <Button.Tag>Positron</Button.Tag>
            <TextBlock>
                Shoot <Run Text="{Binding Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Button}}}"/>s!
            </TextBlock>
        </Button>
        <Button Margin="10" FontSize="30" Click="Button_OnClick">
            <Button.Tag>Tachyon</Button.Tag>
            <TextBlock>
                Shoot <Run Text="{Binding Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Button}}}"/>s!
            </TextBlock>
        </Button>
        <Popup Name="ThePopup" Placement="Center" StaysOpen="False" AllowsTransparency="True"
               PlacementTarget="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type StackPanel}}}">
            <Border Background="White" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="3" CornerRadius="20" Padding="5">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Charge}" FontSize="30"/>
            </Border>
        </Popup>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

[image: Design appearance]

Code-behind:

```
namespace TestPopup {
    public partial class MainWindow : Window {
        ViewModel Vm => (ViewModel) DataContext;
        public MainWindow() { InitializeComponent(); }

        private void Button_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
            var munition = ((Button)sender).Tag;
            munition = munition == null ? "nothing" : $"{munition}s";
            Vm.Charge = $"Emitted {munition}.";
            ThePopup.IsOpen = true;
            var theTextBox = ThePopup.LogicalChildrenBfs().OfType<TextBlock>().Single();
            var theTextBoxDataContext = theTextBox.DataContext;
            // they are the same:
            var areSame = ReferenceEquals(DataContext, theTextBoxDataContext);
        }
    }

    public class ViewModel : MagicallyHandlesAllINotifyPropertyChanged {
        public string Charge { get; set; } = "Initial text";
    }
}
```

Comment: [`Popup`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms749018(v=vs.100).aspx#PopupandtheVisualTree) does not have visual tree until `IsOpen` is set true and then _new window with its own visual tree is created_.

Comment: @dkozl, the object called `ThePopup` (of type `Popup`), and all its descendants have same `DataContext` object reference (as my code above shows, `ReferenceEquals(DataContext, theTextBoxDataContext)` returns `true`)

Comment: That is correct behaviour besides, from what you've posted, it seems initial binding is working as you see _Initial text_. What is `MagicallyHandlesAllINotifyPropertyChanged`? Are you 100% sure it raises `PropertyChanged` for `Charge` property?

Comment: @dkozl, yes, 100%. I verified it many many times before posting this question. I just didn't want to overwhelm with unnecessary information, but it's 100% working.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something here. Which binding is not working? `Popup.PlacementTarget` or `TextBlock.Text`? `Text` binding should work, assuming event is raised, `PlacementTarget` won't work because I don't see `Grid` in your visual tree

Comment: @dkozl, fixed `{x:Type Grid}` to `{x:Type StackPanel}`, thanks. But that's not the issue.

Answer (score 0):

DataBinding is cascaded via the visual tree.
Popup is not part of the visual tree.

One way to fix that is adding x:Name to the RootElement (or any other element that has the relevant DataContext) and in the Binding of the popup add ElementName=...

ex:

```
<Window x:Class="TestPopup.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:l="clr-namespace:TestPopup" **x:Name="MyWindow"**
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <l:ViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <StackPanel>


<Popup Name="ThePopup" **DataContext="{Binding DataContext, ElementName=MyWindow}"**
```

Placement="Center" StaysOpen="False" AllowsTransparency="True"
                   PlacementTarget="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Grid}}}">

Comment: Doesn't work. And again - they all have same `DataContext` object reference anyway.

Comment: Check using Snoop if the Popup has the same data context.

Answer (score 0):

Popups aren't part of the visual tree, so even if you give them the same DataContext it won't be able to resolve it. The way around this issue is to provide it by way of [a proxy binding as explained on this page](http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2011/03/21/wpf-how-to-bind-to-data-when-the-datacontext-is-not-inherited/).